# How to create an emacs diary entry that combines diary-block and diary-cyclic?

Tags: emacs, calendar

I would have thought this was an FAQ,but so far I've been unable to write a search expression that finds it. SO...

I want to write expressions in an emacs diary that uses both the diary-block and diary cyclic functions to select dates. That is, something that marks e.g., rehearsals that take place every Tuesday but only from September 8 through November 12. This seems like something that should be possible, but I can't figure out how to do it from the emacs calendar guides that I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the key point that when you write `%%(...)`, the part after the `%%` is an *arbitrary lisp form*, rather than one of a limited set of options.  Hence the answer is simply:

```el
%%(and (diary-block ...) (diary-cyclic ...))
```

Some other examples of combining things:

```
%%(or (diary-float t 3 2) (diary-float t 3 4))
The 2nd and 4th Wednesday of each month.  (Not a 14-day cycle)

%%(or (diary-float '(1 3 5 7 9 11) 4 3) (diary-float '(2 4 6 8 10 12) 2 3))
Monthly dates alternating between the 3rd Tuesday and the 3rd Thursday
of each month.

%%(my-diary-foo)
Completely custom...
```

Where `my-diary-foo` is a custom function:

```el
;; To be called from diary-sexp-entry, where DATE, ENTRY are bound.
(defvar date)
(defun my-diary-foo ()
  "The first Thursday of the month following the 1st."
  ;; The first Thursday of the month unless the 1st is a Thursday,
  ;; in which case it will be on the 8th (being the 2nd Thursday).
  (if (and (eql (calendar-day-of-week date) 4) ;; Thursday
           (or (eql (calendar-extract-day date) 1)   ;; 1st of the month
               (eql (calendar-extract-day date) 8))) ;; 8th of the month
      (diary-float t 4 2)
    (diary-float t 4 1)))
```

For more information, read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Sexp Diary Entries`

Comment: That's just what I needed, thank you. And if I am supposed to avoid saying 'Thanks' in comments, just where are you supposed to say 'thank you'?

Comment: FWIW I won't complain about anyone saying "thank you" in the comments :)  Please do "accept" the answer if it's resolved the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers